# BindRequired attribute for all parameters in an action

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

In a controller action when you add an attribute [BindRequired] to a parameter, it makes the parameter to be mandatory. But if you have multiple parameters, it gets extremely verbose. Is there a way to have something similar on the action level?

Comment: do you want to avoid writing BindRequired attribute to call columns ?

Comment: @SatishPai On the contrary, I want something like that to call on all parameters of an action without adding it to every action. Something like an attribute that does the same but applied to the action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to create a model and put all the parameters to the model like below:

```
public class Test
{
    [BindRequired]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [BindRequired]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    //other property...
}
```

Controller:

```
public void Post([FromQuery] Test model)
{
     // return statement
}
```

Request url: `https://localhost:portNumber/api/values?id=1&name=aa`

Another way is to custom action filter like below:

```
public class MyActionFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        var keylist = new string[] { "id", "name" };
        var keys = context.HttpContext.Request.Query.Keys;
        foreach(var item in keylist)
        {
            if(!keys.Contains(item))
            {
                context.ModelState.AddModelError(item, $"The {item} need to be provided");
            }
        }
        if (!context.ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            context.Result = new BadRequestObjectResult(
                                                context.ModelState);
        }
    }

}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[MyActionFilter]
public void Post(string id,string name)
{
    // return statement
}
```